# Delete rows based on value of 3 cells

Tags: vba, excel

I am fairly new to VBA so what I am trying to do feels almost impossible.

I have an excel sheet with three columns showing the percentage of toner left.

```
Black   Cyan    Magenta Yellow
6       45      67      100
93      93      5       19
20      40      65      57
```

I want to know if it's possible to create a macro to look at all three columns per row and if all the values are higher than 10, to delete the row and if any of the 3 values is below 10 to keep the row and move on to the next one.

In this case, row 2 and 3 would be kept because there's values below 10 but row 4 would be deleted.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Please provide the VBA code you have been trying to use that is being problematic and the current outcome/issue as described in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: And if you're just looking for a place to start, you'll want to try the [WorksheetFunction.CountIf Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheetfunction-countif-method-excel)

Comment: @tigeravatar the rest of my code is built already and this is something I want to add but I have/had no idea or where I should start. That was the reason for not providing the code. I am currently taking a look at the link you provided.

Comment: @Jerry I have not created the code yet since I don't know how to start it.  I was wondering if it was possible to do such an action. Currently I am looking at "If" link provided above.

Comment: @FabricioMartinez StackOverflow is unfortunately not a tutorial website. I would suggest to try going through a tutorial and when/if you get stuck with a problem, you will be welcome to ask about it, with all the details I mentioned in my other comment.

Comment: @Jerry No worries. I understand. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
For i = Sheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row to 2 Step -1
    If Cells(i, Column1).Value2 > 10 And Cells(i, Column2).Value2 > 10 And Cells(i, Column3).Value2 > 10 Then
        Rows(i).Delete
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: This almost worked. I was unaware that "And" could be used to keep the "If" going. However, the script also considers blanks less than 10. I will go ahead and try to figure that out on my end. Thanks a bunch! and sorry for the hassle.